Como cargar lista de datos de un ID Especifico asp net EF?
Holas soy nuevo con entity framework, tengo un pequeño CRUD de dos tablas
create table Cliente(
 IdCliente int primary key identity(1,1),
 NumeroDocumento varchar(25)
 )

 GO

 create table DETALLE_ESTADO(
 IdDetalle int primary key identity(1,1),
 IdCliente int,
 Estado varchar(60),
 fecha date,
 CONSTRAINT FK_IdVenta FOREIGN KEY (IdCliente) REFERENCES Cliente(IdCliente)
 )

logre cargar registros de esta forma

ahora quiero cargar los datos del boton Detalle y use esto en la vista
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cliente.NumeroDocumento)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Estado)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fecha)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

</table>

Para cargar los datos de clientes en el controlador use esto, pero ahora no se como usarlo para listar los registros de cada cliente
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
 {
     if (id == null)
     {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }
     Cliente cliente = db.Cliente.Find(id);
     if (cliente == null)
     {
         return HttpNotFound();
     }
     return View(cliente);
 }

Lo que necesito ayuda es que cuando le de en el boton Detalles, me cargue todos los registros de ese numero de documento, como la siguiente consulta
select NumeroDocumento, Estado,fecha 
  from Cliente left join  DETALLE_ESTADO
  on Cliente.IdCliente = DETALLE_ESTADO.IdCliente
  where NumeroDocumento like '894204'


muchas Gracias
